# comparing CSV files in Perl

Tags: perl, csv

I have two large CSV files which I need to compare on a daily base:

file1:

```
"Record number";"€ price"
"000001";"€ 19,95"
"000002";"€ 20,50"
```

file2:

```
record number;price;date
000001;18,95;01-01-2014
000002;21,50;02-02-2014
```

file1 contains line feeds after every record
file2 contains line feed and carriage return after every record.

I'm looking for a way in Perl to compare file1 with file2 based on record number, and print differences on the price column in a seperate file. (record number, price and date).

Hope anyone can give some advice on how to approach this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what version of perl are you using?

Comment: Please do not format your question using html, use the Markup instead, check the help if you are unsure.

Comment: Most every CSV question related to Perl includes Text::CSV or Text::CSV_XS somewhere in the answer.  Have you gotten started writing anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are quicker and more efficient ways to do this, but below should do the job you describe. I have compared the two files by creating a hash therefore I have assumed that the record numbers are unique. I have commented the code to explain each step

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  

use strict;
use warnings;

#declare hashes and arrays
my %file1_price;
my %file2_price;
my %file2_date;
my @file1_records;

#open the two files with the data
open (FILE1,'</path/to/file1.txt');
open (FILE2,'</path/to/file2.txt');

#open a third file to write the data out to
open (FILE3,'>/write/to/new_file.txt');

#get rid of the headers in both files
my @file1 = (<FILE1>);
my $file1_header = shift(@file1);

my @file2 = (<FILE2>);
my $file2_header = shift(@file2);

#start a loop in file 1 and change the data format to compare to file 2
foreach my $file1_data (@file1){
chomp $file1_data;

my ($file1_record, $file1_price) = split(/;/,$file1_data);

# get rid of the quotes in both variables
$file1_record =~s/"//g;
$file1_price =~s/"//g;

#get rid of the € and substitute the comma for a decimal point 
$file1_price =~s/€//g;
$file1_price =~s/,/./g;

#create a hash for the price for later comparison
$file1_price{$file1_record} = $file1_price;

push @file1_records, $file1_record;

}

#start a loop in file 2 similar to the above loop ready to compare to file 1    
foreach my $file2_data (@file2){
chomp $file2_data;

my ($file2_record, $file2_price, $file2_date) = split(/;/,$file2_data);

#substitute the comma for a decimal point
$file2_price =~s/,/./g;

#create hashes of the data for final comparison below
$file2_price{$file2_record} = $file2_price;
$file2_date{$file2_record} = $file2_date;

}   

#final loop to compare both files' information  
foreach my $record (@file1_records){

#find the difference between the two prices 
my $difference = $file1_price{$record} - $file2_price{$record};

#print out to file
print FILE3 "$record, $file1_price{$record}, $file2_price{$record}, $difference,$file2_date{$record}\n";    

}
```

Comment: `$file1_price{$file1_record} = $file1_price;` does not exactly look correct. You are assigning the old value of the same variable to itself.